# iPhone equivalent of Timer and TimerTask for periodic tasks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, timertask

I'm trying to port an Android app to an iPhone. On Android I could easily process data every 60 seconds by using a Timer class with TimerTasks using scheduleAtFixedRate:
**timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,15000, epochLengthMs);**

Thank you!

Is there something similar I can use on iPhone?

```
protected void startTimer(){

    if(timerStarted){
        //avoid duplicate timers! 
    }else{

        running = true;
        timerStarted = true;

        if(D)Log.w(TAG,"*Timer Started*");
        timer = new Timer();
        readyToProcess = true;
        EpochCounterTask task = new EpochCounterTask();
        AutoSaveTask saveTask = new AutoSaveTask();

        //give statMagnitude enough time to get values
        //after 15 sec, every 60 sec
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,15000, epochLengthMs);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(saveTask,645000, 600000);

        }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create two NSTimers - one for the epoch counter and one for the autosave task. Something like this:

```
- (void)startTimer {

if(timerStarted){
    //avoid duplicate timers! 
}else{

    running = true;
    timerStarted = true;

    readyToProcess = true;

    epochTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:epochSeconds 
                                        target:self
                                        selector:@selector(processEpochTimer:)
                                        userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES] retain];

    autosaveTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:autosaveSeconds 
                                        target:self
                                        selector:@selector(processAutosaveTimer:)
                                        userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES] retain];
    }
}
```

You also need to define the following handler methods, which are called when the timers fire:

```
- (void)processEpochTimer:(NSTimer*)theTimer;
- (void)processAutosaveTimer:(NSTimer*)theTimer;
```

Comment: This works great. The timer fires every so many seconds. Thank's for the retain at the end, I forgot about that, which might've had some bad consequences down the line!

Comment: The timers are retained by the runloop when they are added to it so they remain 'live' anyway. The 'retain' here is just for strict compliance with the Objective C memory management conventions. I'm assuming that epochTimer and autosaveTimer are data members in your class and that you need to retain them so you can stop the timers at a later date (call invalidate then release).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Answer (score 2):

take a look at http://www.iphoneexamples.com/   **Timer**

Timers
This timer will call myMethod every 1 second.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
    target:self 
    selector:@selector(myMethod:) 
    userInfo:nil 
    repeats:YES];
```

What if you need to pass an object to myMethod? Use the "userInfo" property. 
1. First create the Timer

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
    target:self 
    selector:@selector(myMethod:) //don't forget the ":"
    userInfo:myObject 
    repeats:YES];
```

1. Then pass the NSTimer object to your method:

   -(void) myMethod:(NSTimer*)timer
         // Now I can access all the properties and methods of myObject
         [[timer userInfo] myObjectMethod];

To stop a timer, use "invalidate":

```
[myTimer invalidate];
myTimer = nil; // ensures we never invalidate an already invalid Timer
```

Comment: I checked the documentation, and it mentions that the selector should be of the form: -(void)processDataForTimer:(NSTimer*)theTimer , accepting a timer as an argument

Comment: yes it should be. I also have included that only... so what the problem??